# Appcelerator sidemenu redirect to another screen creating multiple screen

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am using [this sidemenu module](https://github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu) in my app.

In sidemenu i have option like home, setting etc.
When i click on setting, it redirect to setting page.
Now problem is when setting page is opened and i open side menu using swipe and again click on setting then it will again open setting screen on previous one.
Means it creating 2 setting screen.
If i repeat it again then it will creating again setting scree.
How do i prevent this?

My code for screen redirection is here

```
var win = Alloy.createController('Setting').getView();
window.closeOpenView();
$.navWindow.openWindow(win);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store last opened page:

Add this outside the click function

```
var openWindow = '';
```

And this inside the click function

```
if (openWindow == 'Setting') return;

openWindow = 'Setting'
var win = Alloy.createController('Setting').getView();
window.closeOpenView();
$.navWindow.openWindow(win);
```

This assumes this is in a function, which I guess it is because it is a click handler. If not, wrap it in a function

Comment: well.. then other code is apparently also relevant. Because  this will prevent the setting window from opening twice

Comment: of course, `openWindow = ''` needs to be put outside the click function. Fixed it in answer