# Appcelerator call function everytime window open

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am using navigation window in my app.
I want to reset variable when every time window appear.
I tried

```
$.win.addEventListener("focus", function(e){
    alert("window appear");
});
```

This is not calling. So i tried following:

```
$.win.addEventListener("open", function(e){
     alert("window appear");
});
```

But this is only call when first time it open..it is not called when screen open from back clicked.

Comment: Do you develop on Android only?

Comment: No...actually i am in ios

Comment: weird...focus should works. Be careful with focus + alert message, because when you close an alert, it will call the focus callback again and you will have a loop

Comment: Console.log also not working

Comment: Not console.log but Ti.API.info

Comment: Ti.API.info also not working. if i use "open" then it show in log only once but "focus" is not even once

Comment: So you keep an reference to the closed window, and re-open it using `.open()`? Perhaps share your code on how you re-open it?

Answer (score 0):

Focus should work if you minimise the app or show the status bar, blur will also be triggered when the window loses focus.

It sounds like you are never closing the window or you are registering the event listeners inside another function, ensure the event listeners are defined at the top level (not in any other functions).

Console.log doesn't work very well in titanium use Ti.API.info('Alert message');

Comment: I am usgin side menu module...in this module problem is -> look at my this post - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407127/appcelerator-sidemenu-redirect-to-another-screen-creating-multiple-screen/35407547#35407547   this solution is working fine..but i want to set OpenWindow to nil every time you return to home screen. So i tried focus for home screen...this variable should be update to nil from whenever you come to home screen..either from history or from anywhere else

Comment: you can't set the function to null you need to remove it to prevent it firing again with win.removeEventListener('open')... ensuring it is the same code as your open function

Comment: i don't want to set function null...i just want to set variable "OpenWindow" null

Comment: As I said you can't set it to null, but you can remove it, if you want to change a variable then declare it in the app.js file / alloy.js file or use Alloy.Globals.propertyName (if you are using alloy) and then you can set the variable wherever and whenever you need to and it will also be valid while the application is running.

Comment: My variable is already in app.js...when you open setting screen from side menu then variable change to OpenWindow = 'Setting'. Now when you come back from setting to home then i want to set it like OpenWindow = ' ' ..so i want that how can i trigger that even from which i know home screen is open...so that i can change it to OpenWindow = ' '

Comment: Would it not be better to set the openWindow variable on the click of the menu item in the side menu, then this is no longer an issue.

Comment: it i not set that variable then another issue which i mention in first comment